# Passing Data-ID Safely - Security Issue[Laravel]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I have posts that users do and a button that opens a modal and a user can can edit the posts.

I currently have a button that has a `data-id` and passes the id to the modal which then in the modal I set the update id that and on submit it submits.

This is an issue because what If a user types in another id like `400` instead of that posts id which could be `50`.

How can I be sure to only update that id / pass that id.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take `hidden input tag` for post-id , and server side check that if post's user_id is equal to logged in user's id then only update the post .

```
public function update(Request $request,$id){
    $post=Post::find($id);
    if($post){
        if($post->user_id == auth()->user()->id){
             // update post
        }else{
             // a person can not update post , redirect or show error        
        }
    }else{
        return view('error404');  // post not found,show 404 error page
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest` to perform validation, you can utilize the `authorize` method.

> The form request class also contains an authorize method. Within this
>   method, you may check if the authenticated user actually has the
>   authority to update a given resource.

Let's say you're route is ...

```
Route::get('posts/edit/{post}', ['uses' => "PostController@update"]);
```

Then in your `PostRequest`, add an authorize method to validate the user editing the post.

```
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    $post = Post::find($this->route('post'));
    return $post && $this->user()->can('update', $post);
}
```

If you would like to customize the response when the authorize method fails, you can override the `failedAuthorization()` function.

```
/**
 * Handle a failed authorization attempt.
 *
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
 */
protected function failedAuthorization()
{
    // Spank user.
    throw new AuthorizationException('This action is unauthorized.');
}
```